# Представление на главной странице блоков

Tags: asp.net, c#, mvc

Здравствуйте!
 Подскажите как реализовать следующее.
 На главной странице есть блок Новостей. Этот блок должен в замостите от контента (главная сейчас страница или внутренняя) отображаться по разному. На главной блок должен быть широкий и отображать к примеру пару новостей, если находимся в каком то другом разделе, то блок Новостей должен быть узкий, если зашли в раздел новости, там этот блок широкий и более информативный. Получается три вида блока новостей.
 Разделять на три разные вьюшки не хочется. Есть более хитрый способ, подскажите.
 Использую представления Razor
 С# VS2012 MVC4

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите разные отображения элемента в разных представлениях, то попробуйте использовать секции.
В layout на месте элемента пишите:

```
@RenderSection("News", optional:true)
```

А в представлении пишете "обработчик":

```
@section News
{

}
```

Почитать про них можно [тут](https://www.olegaxenow.com/2010/12/aspnet-mvc-3-razor.html) или [тут](https://web.archive.org/web/20150325061643/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ruscottgu/archive/2010/07/20/introducing-razor-a-new-view-engine-for-asp-net.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать статический хелпер, возвращающий данные для новостей, допустим с полями A,B,C, и дать идентификаторы разделам сайта, ну или по Request.Url проверять. Если один раздел - выводить A, если другой - B... как вариант.